# I can not get expected output by like operator, where field store multiple integer value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

This is the **user table** and company_ids is a varchar filed which store multiple integer values with a comma separator,

I like to get those of users who have company id **1**,   but 81 or 61 or 101 will not be counted because 81 is not equal to 1

I used **like** operator, but it does not return me an accurate result.

**Expected Output:** The number of expected users is 3, whose ids are 550,551,582

[image]

Comment: Your table design is bad. Can you change it? Never store multiple values in a single column!

Comment: I am at the stage of project ending, it is not possible to change now.